# TypeError: SVG is not a function

Tags: typescript, svg.js

I'm importing Svg.js into my typescript project. When I call SVG I receive the following error. 
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: SVG is not a function`

I've tried to import Svg.js in different ways, but that doesn't seem to be the issue. I also tried to call on 'SVG' in different ways as well.
Using Svg.js version `@svgdotjs/svg.js": "^3.0.11`

Ex:

```
import * as SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
const svgjs: any = SVG;
export default svgjs;
```

```
    let draw = new SVG.Doc('drawing');
    let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
```

The above method returns `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: SVG.Doc is not a constructor`

Here is how I import Svg.js.
`import * as SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'`

This is how I use 'SVG'.

```
let draw = SVG('drawing');
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
```

Comment: There is a PR which fixes Typescript issues for svg.js v3. However, it seems like you mix up 2.x code with the new 3.x release. In 3.x you do `SVG().addTo('#id')` or similar

Answer (score 2):

```
import SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js/src/svg" //v3.0

let draw = SVG().addTo('#drawing').viewbox(0, 0, 300, 140)
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({fill: "#f06"})
```

Comment: This worked for me. I used .size(...) instead of viewbox(...).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend on your Babel configuration, but in my experience, `import * as X` creates an object that wraps up all the exports of a module. So you'd have to call:

```
let draw = SVG.default('drawing');
```

Or better, convert the import to `import X`:

```
import SVG from "@svgdotjs/svg.js";
...
let draw = SVG('drawing');
```

Answer (score 0):

SVG() should now work correctly in 3.0.12